# Unity SmoothDamp not working as intended

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok, I got a series of cards that will move 1 by 1 to the center of the camera each and every time the user clicks.

`StageContainer` is the parent of all cards. This is the one that will move making it look like the cards are moving instead.

First I this is my code without smoothdamp

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        StartCoroutine ( ProcessFocus() );
        frames++;
    }
}

IEnumerator ProcessFocus() {
    curPos = StageContainer.transform.localPosition;
    nextPos = curPos;
    nextPosX = nextPos.x - 400;
    nextPos.x = nextPosX;
    StageContainer.transform.localPosition = nextPos;
    yield break;
}
```

The code above gives me the instant change of cards on the center of the camera. No transitions, animation whatsoever.. the point is it works.
Now when I change this :

```
StageContainer.transform.localPosition = nextPos;
```

to this :

```
float smoothTime = 0.3F;
Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
StageContainer.transform.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(curPos, nextPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);
```

I assumed it will transition from current X point to next X point,
but every time I mouse click, it just move bit by bit like 10~20 X points

I have no clue why it behave like that. Please help.

Comment: Please don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It's generally a good idea to read tag descriptions before adding them to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coroutine needs to keep running until your movement is completed.

```
IEnumerator ProcessFocus() {

    curPos = StageContainer.transform.localPosition;
    nextPos = curPos;
    nextPosX = nextPos.x - 400;
    nextPos.x = nextPosX;

    float smoothTime = 0.3F;
    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    while(this.transform.position != nextPos) {
       StageContainer.transform.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(curPos, nextPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);
       yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your code runs once and then exits the coroutine. To run the coroutine for some amount of time, you have to yield return [some `YieldInstruction`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/YieldInstruction.html) instances. In this case, I suspect that you want to [use `WaitForEndOfFrame`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html).

Comment: Can you post your updated code and elaborate on what exactly doesn't work?